# How do I parse a WebPage using HTML tags in VBScript

Tags: parsing, vbscript

I try to extract the price of Bitcoin from https://coinmarketcap.com/ using VBScript.
I have the following HTML code:

```html
<td class="no-wrap text-right" data-sort="4329.6071152">
<a class="price" href="/currencies/bitcoin/#markets" data-btc="1.0" data-usd="4329.6071152">$4,329.61</a>
</td>
```

So I wrote this script for the vbs file:

```
set objIE =nothing
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Visible = false
objIE.Navigate "https://coinmarketcap.com/"

Do
   WScript.Sleep 100
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

msgbox objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("/currencies/bitcoin/#markets")
objIE.Quit()
```

My expected result is "4329.6071152" but the actual result is:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a collection of HTML nodes with your query. You should try a more specific one and also getting its attributes:

```
MsgBox objIE.document.QuerySelectorAll("a[href='/currencies/bitcoin/#markets']").Item(0).getAttribute("data-usd")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks iBug, I didn't know that in VBScript you can use CSSSelector. This is very usefull !

Comment: If I want to extract "$4,329.61" how can I do? Because it's a little bit different

Comment: @BOB You can use `.innerText` for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the row of the table has the id attribute set. You can get the text content of the cell this way:

```
objIE.document.GetElementById("id-bitcoin").Cells(3).InnerText
```

Comment: I saw it `<tr id="id-bitcoin" class="odd" role="row">`